# Alpha equivalent subgoals

Tags: alpha-equivalence, de-bruijn-indexing

I'm working on proof automation methods using Lean, and have noticed that quite often there will be many subgoals generated which are alpha-equivalent, which I would like to discard. For example, the subgoals generated from `intro x y` vs `intro a b`. Is there a way to convert subgoals into a format (e.g. de Bruijn indices for variables) to prevent this from happening, or a simple way to check for alpha equivalence? Thanks!

Comment: Could you quantify "quite often"? Note that you can use the `<;>` tactical to dispose of similar subgoals.

Comment: @AndrejBauer You would be surprised how common it is for a language model to produce many different variations of `intro a` as a tactic prediction.

Comment: @AndrejBauer It tends to vary by the specific goal. The initial goals (root nodes for the search tree used by the learning algorithms) usually have the most of these redundancies (as Jason mentioned, generally variations on things like `intro`, or `refine` etc.). In some cases, I've observed > 70% of tactics being like this, which of course explodes the search tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on what sort of automation you are doing.  If you are working with language models and *only* have access to the goal state text, then unfortunately I think your best bet is just heuristics.  For example, you could find the local variables `a`, `b`, `h` in:

```
  a b : ℕ
  h : a < b
  ⊢ ∀ (n : ℕ), a + n < b + n
```

with simple string operations and then do a find ans replace.  But of course that would be a huge mess.  (Maybe the best would be to use a LLM to do the substitution for you. :) )

If you have more access to Lean's metaprogramming framework, or the ability to run tactics to manipulate the goal state, then there are a number of good options:

- Output along with the pretty printed string an sexpr of the full term.  It would be easier to compare it for alpha-equivalence.
- I don't know if there already is a tactic to convert everything to a alpha normal form, but you could write one without too much work.
- You could traverse the goal expressions and generate a hash of the goal.  (The expressions are stored with deBruin indices so this wouldn't be hard. [Edit: Local hypothesis aren't stored as deBruin indices as I think about it, but still it shouldn't be too bad.])
- If both goals live simultaneously in Lean memory, you could also inspect two goals to see if they are alpha equivalent.

It is hard to know what your exact setting is so the three pieces of advice are:

- Go to the Lean Zulip and explain your situation in more detail, maybe the metaprogramming stream.
- Look at the Lean metaprogramming book: https://github.com/leanprover-community/lean4-metaprogramming-book
- Look through the available tools already existing in the code for writing tactics and such.  There might already be useful tools there.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jason Rute. I am indeed working with LLMs (specifically LeanDojo as the Lean interface, if you're familiar). Maybe something along the lines of concatenating the tactic prediction from the model with another tactic converting it into a normal form could work, provided something already exists for this.